# How to configure specific Zookeeper path to commit the offsets ,when check point is disabled?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

If checkpointing is not enabled, the Kafka consumer will periodically commit the offsets to Zookeeper.Is it possible to configure the zookeeper path?

Answer (score 1):

Can not do this. because if kafka use zookeeper to store the offset, and then zookeeper path is hard coded in the kafka code.

The path is like this :

> /consumers/{yourConsumerGroup}/offsets/{yourFancyTopic}/{partitionId}

You can not config this.